# How to get the COUNT in SQL - When you have 2 JOINS and a Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a database which has multiple tables. For a specific case, I need to show the DISTINCT COUNT along with the COUNT of the users for each Activity. The idea is to get the all the distinct count of users as well the count of users from the Activity_Table with a LEFT JOIN on LOGIN_TABLE + PROFILE_TABLE.

The activity table has the most number of users, therefore, I am using a left join on profile and login table. Additionally, I am trying to get the users COUNT & DISTICT COUNT from all the three tables, where the data IS NOT NULL and I have strict date range which I have to also take in account.

I have been trying to the use the query below:

```
SELECT a.ACTIVITY, COUNT(DISTINCT a.USERID) as "DCount_Only", COUNT(a.PL_USERID) as "Count_Only"
FROM ACTIVITY_TABLE a

LEFT JOIN LOGIN_TABLE b ON a.USERID = b.USERID 
LEFT JOIN PROFILE_TABLE c ON a.USERID = c.USERID

WHERE FORMAT(a.ACTIVITY_DATE, 'yyyy-MM') = '2020-12'

      AND a.ACTIVITY_DATE >= '06-11-2020'
      AND b.LOGIN_DATE >= '06-11-2020'
      AND c.REGISTRATION_DATE >= '06-11-2020'

      AND b.USERID IS NOT NULL
      AND c.USERID IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY a.ACTIVITY
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT a.USERID) DESC, COUNT(a.USERID) DESC;
```

Result of the Query:

[image: .]

The above query gives me the correct **distinct** count for the whatever date I specify. However, I am unable to get the correct count.

I would appreciate any help or guidance to resolve this.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't have a `FORMAT()` function.

Comment: No! My bad, I am using SQL Server. I have no clue about MYSQL.

Comment: The question I linked to is for MySQL, but the same approach should work with any SQL RDBMS.

Comment: I tried but no luck!!! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Update the question and show what you tried. Then we can reopen and help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that using this two conditions

```
AND b.USERID IS NOT NULL
AND c.USERID IS NOT NULL
```

converts your **left join** into an **inner join**?
It is because any USERID from right that is not matched to the left will get dropped.
if that's so, the solution would be to use a sub-query, something like:

```
SELECT 
  x,y,z
FROM
  table1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE userid IS NOT NULL)
;
```